# When building an app with Ionic or flutter and strapi or wordpress as the backend, where does the Azure AD SSO authentication happen?

Tags: wordpress, ldap, azure-active-directory, strapi

When building an app with Ionic or flutter and strapi or wordpress as the headless backend, where does the Azure AD SSO authentication happen?

Would LDAP need to be configured in the front end with Ionic or Flutter, or in the back end with Strapi or Wordpress?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose your [authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols). Based on authentication flow only  authentication will happen on front end or backend. For example, if we choose  Implicit grant flow then auth will work on front end authentication without backend requests.

LDAP is not required to configure in your scenario since you are trying to authenticate via Azure AD. It is only required in scenarios like when you have an On-Prem AD environment and require authentication.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_2adGjX3iybgAqTX&Q_CHL=gl
>